# How to get most probable className from TensorFlow.js in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, mobilenet, image-classification

**What I want to do:** I want to get the className with the highest probability from the TensorFlow.js image classification with mobileNet. I want to get the className as a String.

**Problem:** I have no clue how to isolate the className as a String. Is there a command for this? or do you have any idea how I can solve my problem?

**My code:**

```
theAi();

async function theAi() {
    const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs'),
    mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet'),
    tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node'),
    fs = require('fs-extra');

    const imageBuffer = await fs.readFile("./jesus.jpg"),
    tfimage = tfnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer),
    mobilenetModel = await mobilenet.load();  

    const results = await mobilenetModel.classify(tfimage);
    console.log(results);
};
```

**And the output:**

```
[
  {
    className: 'chain mail, ring mail, mail, chain armor, chain armour, ring armor, ring armour',
    probability: 0.5979475378990173
  },
  { className: 'vestment', probability: 0.14261281490325928 },
  { className: 'fountain', probability: 0.03441018983721733 }
]
```

So in this case I would want to get the String ('chain mail, ring mail, mail, chain armor, chain armour, ring armor, ring armour').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure javascript question. If you get this result, you can just search for m
aximum:

```js
const maxClass = result.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return (prev.probability > current.probability) ? prev : current;
})["className"];
```

Comment: Hello, could you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64621656/can-we-show-underfitting-with-mobilenet